# SKAction applyForce not working?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I want to mimic gravity without using physicsBody.
However when I do this

```
let applyForce = SKAction.applyForce(CGVector(dx:0,dy:-9.8), duration:duration)
sprite.run(applyForce)
```

Nothing happens. Why is that so?

Comment: The sprite needs to have a SKPhysicsBody.

Comment: How can you think it can be possible to apply a force to something that is not a physical body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you are calling is run from your sprite, but *targets* the sprite's physics body.

You would need to create your own version of `applyForce()` that doesn't require a physics body.